# Is it possible that grid search would fail in two dimensional feature space?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, estimators

Grid search suffers from the curse of dimensionality. But is there any case(any hypothetical distribution of data) in a two dimensional feature space where the data’s binary classification using Grid Search would yield very poor results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid search *at appropriate resolution* will always produce excellent results. The problem arises when getting to that appropriate resolution is intractable. Numerical approximations become infeasible very quickly as the dimension of the data increases, but it's entirely possible to have an intractably large space to explore in just two dimensions. Consider a function sampled from Brownian Motion: there will be lots of local optima, the data is not smoothed by increasing resolution, and the spread of the data relative to the global mean doesn't ever really decrease over the entire domain (as opposed to something like the normal pdf where the values are all approximately equal to the mean (0) for the entire support, except within the 99% confidence interval).

So to summarize, think of it this way: pick some minimum resolution R for your search. In high dimensional space, you will consider grid search intractable if you need at minimum K iterations to search your space at resolution R. If in two dimensions you need more than K iterations to search at R resolution, you have exactly the same problem as you had in the higher dimension search.

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot actually visualize your idea clearly here. I cannot think of an example in 2 dimensions where I might need at least k iterations to search at R resolution. Is there any place, i can look to get this idea in depth? Or may be could you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Let's say you want unit resolution. let's say all possible variables have a domain of [0,100] for simplicity. In one dimension, k=100. In two dimension, k= 100^2, etc., so in N dimensions k=100^N. This is what I mean by "numerical approximations become intractable *quickly* as the dimension increases:" the number of iterations grows exponentially. Let's say we determine that the maximum feasible iterations on our hardware is 1e9. If the domain of our variables is [0,1e5], then we can't search the entire space with unit resolution in two dimensions in under 1e9 iterations.